# Does MS SQL Server support a read-only near-real-time mirror for handling queries?

Tags: sql-server

I'm a novice on MS SQL Server. With Postgres, we often set up a server pair where all inserts/updates etc go to the primary, and reads can go to the replica. We write the application software such that it keeps two database connections open to the two databases, and accesses the read-only replica for queries whenever up-to-the-second data is not needed. We do this quite often to reduce the load on the primary DB.

Is it possible to do this with recent versions of MS SQL Server? I was told it's not.

Comment: `I was told it's not.` really? SQL Server has this for almost 30 years through replication and 17 years with mirroring. Never mind that read replicas are a quick&dirty alternative to proper reporting databases or data warehouses. For OLTP workloads, if reading is slow you need to check what's going wrong - are indexes missing? Bad queries that can't use indexes? A read-only replica will keep your DB from crashing but won't fix schema problems

Comment: SNAPSHOT isolation reduces read/write blocking too at the expense of increased TempDB IO.

Comment: [Memory optimized tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/overview-and-usage-scenarios?view=sql-server-ver16) can be used for *very* high transaction rates, increasing performance by using a different, in-memory concurrency model. You can even [combine these with columnstore indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/get-started-with-columnstore-for-real-time-operational-analytics?view=sql-server-ver16) to provide almost real-time analytics

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is why I asked the question: I was not able to get clear responses from the one or two people I spoke with and by searching.

Can you please post a URL or two I can read?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do this with recent versions of MS SQL Server? I was
> told it's not.

Told by whom? [SQL Server Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server) allow secondary database replicas to be used for read-only queries, in addition to HA/DR purposes.

Secondary replicas may be configured as either synchronous or asynchronous, which affects the latency before changes are visible on secondary database replicas. This is typically near real-time with synchronous commit mode unless the secondary node is taxed with a heavy workload. The delay is longer with asynchronous but the advantage of asynch is that commits on the primary do not need to wait before changes are hardened on the secondary, which can reduce commit time on the primary.

Comment: I suspect this won't be needed if the correct indexes and queries are used. Never mind snapshot isolation, in-memory tables, columnstores or other features that remove the need for read-only replicas

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, agreed query/index tuning and leveraging other features can mitigate the need for read-only secondaries but not necessarily eliminate it.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me read further. In my case, I was not interested in synchronous replication -- my use-case would be happy with a few minutes of delay, and would be relieved to eliminate the overhead of distributed commits.